# How to get one variable printed recusively with varying serial number

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to print a recursive variable using a `for` loop:

```matlab
w
i=0;
for i<=10;
    w('i')
end
```

I am trying to print a simple thing.I have a variable named `W` and using a `for` loop from 1 to 10, I want to print `w1,w2,w3,w4,w5` etc. How can I do that?

Comment: You might want to read a tutorial on MATLAB, as this is about as basic as it gets. [The MathWorks themselves](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) published a good tutorial I can recommend.

Comment: What is a "recursive variable"? Also, you really shouldn't be using dynamically-named variables. Use some sort of indexed container, instead, like a vector or array.

Comment: i am sorry i am very new to programming, i took a break from studies and went to non-tech side of things for 3 years, kind of coping up with everything now

Comment: @CodyGray i couldn't find a more suitable name, i am trying to solve inverse dynamics of a 3 -link serial robot and using recursive newton eulor algorithm for it, if i define every  variable by myself the number of variables would be very high and tedious to write individualy, instead i though if i can recursively get these variables printed and slim down the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
for i = 1:10
    disp("w"+i)
end
```

This is the output that I got:

```
w1
w2
w3
w4
w5
w6
w7
w8
w9
w10
```

Comment: i tried this and it worked, thank you. i am trying to use these variables to store matrices in a 3-link serial robot.